# Compiler optimization pass joining identical function definitions together (or specializing them)

Tags: reference-request, compilers, functional-programming

Consider this program transformation, *in any direction*, written in ANF:

```
let f = λx.a in                     let f = λx.a in
let g = λx.a in         <->         b[f/g]
b
```

In the above, `f` doesn't appear free in `a`, and both `f` and `g` appear free in `b` (so only `f` appears free in `b[f/g]`). Or course, this can be written in a [CPS IR](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2007/10/compilingwithcontinuationscontinued.pdf) as well:

```
letfun f x k = a in                     letfun f a k = a in
letfun g x k = a in         <->         b[f/g]
b
```

Are there any papers on compilers which mention or study the above rules for optimization, *preferably* treating the IR as a rewriting system? Looking from left to right, this looks like *common subexpression elimination*, as I'm joining two equivalent function definitions into a single one, but I don't remember seeing this being applied to function definitions. Looking from right to left, this looks like *function specialization*, but I'm not sure where this been approached through rewriting. Though I'm most interested in ANF and CPS, any refereces with similar rules for SSA (joining or spliting equivalent functions or blocks) would be welcome as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason why this can't be thought of as common subexpression elimination, except of course that it's made trickier by requiring some kind of $\alpha$-renaming.

Another way to think of this is as a *fold transformation*. This isn't "fold" like in Haskell, a specific iteration pattern over a list, but the opposite of "unfolding" (i.e. inlining).

Optimisations based on unfold/fold were (and probably still are) particularly popular in compilers for logic languages. See, for example: Seki (1993), *[Unfold/fold transformation of general logic programs for the well-founded semantics](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0743106693900218)*.

You can see the connection by thinking of it this way. Going from left to right is "fold" of the definition of `f`, and from right to left is "unfold" of the same definition:

```
let f = λx.a in                     let f = λx.a in
let g = λx.a in         <->         let g = f
b                                   in b
```

The reason why you probably haven't discovered this is that it's not usually thought of like common subexpression elimination, but rather a technique for partial evaluation. The "fold" transformation is [how you generate recursive definitions](https://foldoc.org/unfold/fold).

Most proof assistants based on lambda calculus have [a "fold" tactic](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proofs/writing-proofs/equality.html#coq:tacn.fold).

For more information, see: Zhu (1994), *[How powerful are folding/unfolding transformations?](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-functional-programming/article/how-powerful-are-foldingunfolding-transformations/851C3EA436ACA3556B782F2E9F499D92)*

Comment: You might also enjoy [Hash consing modulo alpha equivalence](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3453483.3454088) which addresses the renaming.

Comment: Ohh, thanks! You're right, I wasn't seeing this as partial evaluation, even though I was aware that I could show this transformation correct by undoing a function inline and then applying an eta reduction (or the other way around, of course). This makes perfect sense.